# How to implement a buffer whose size depends on the consumer and producer speed with RxJava?

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

The requirements are as follows:

1. When the producer is faster than the consumer, the produced items shall be buffered, until the buffer is full. When the buffer is full, the producer shall not be requested to produce new items anymore (back pressure).
2. When the consumer is faster than the producer, the buffered items are emitted to compensate. If the buffer gets empty, then a starvation will occur, but there is no much thing we can do in that case.
3. The goal of the buffer is to reduce the risk of starvation; therefore, it should remain full as long as the producer is faster than the consumer.

I've tried different flowable operators. The one that is very close to these requirements is observeOn with a buffer size. But there is some magic behind this operator: when the buffer is full, it is progressively emptied until its size gets below 25% of its total capacity, and during this process no item is requested to the producer.

Which operator, or combination of operators shall I use to fulfill these requirements?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are onBackpressureBuffer methods with capacity and strategy parameters. Read more https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Backpressure-(2.0)#onbackpressurebufferint-capacity

Comment: what's wrong with the `observeOn` request pattern? What requirement is not met by it?

Comment: with the observeOn operator, when the buffer is 75% full, items are taken from the buffer and the producer is no longer requested to produce new item, until the buffer reaches 25% of its full capacity. The risk is that the producer may slow down at the worse moment, i.e. when the buffer is at 25% of its capacity. Then, the buffer has a small amount of items left to compensate and avoid a starvation. I should add a requirement for that

Comment: `Flowable.observeOn` requests the buffer size upfront and requests 75% of the buffer size once the item count reaches 25%. The free parameter is the buffer size here so you could, say, use a 4096 element buffer knowin that having 1024 elements processed is usually enough time for the producer to catch up. Also make sure the producer runs in its own dedicated thread via `subscribeOn` otherwise you may end up with the producer and consumer running in sync on the same thread.

Comment: @akarnokd sure, but the 25%-75% capacity variation is too large. If I need to buffer at least 50 Mbytes of data, the buffer may store up to 150 Mbytes of data, depending on the variation of the transfer rate between the producer and the consumer.

Answer (score 0):

Use multiple `rebatchRequests` (which uses observeOn under the covers) to artificially increase the level at which further requests are made.

Answer (score 0):

I finally came to the conclusion that a custom flowable operator could be an acceptable solution to both manage overflow (via back pressure) and underflow (via a buffer that actually behaves as a reservoir of elements to avoid starvation).

When this operator is connected to the flowable pipeline, the reservoir of elements is filled with elements emitted by the producer. The consumer takes the elements stored in the reservoir on demand. The producer and consumer operate on two different schedulers.

**Overflow situation:**

- When the reservoir gets full, the producer is no longer requested to emit
  new elements (owing to the back-pressure facility of the pipeline).

**Underflow situation:**

- The reservoir is used to feed the consumer with elements, on demand.

**Life cycle**

- Buffer phase: the reservoir is filled until it gets full. During this phase, the consumer does not receive any element.
- Transfer phase: the consumer takes the elements stored in the reservoir when needed; the producer stores elements in the reservoir as long as it's not full.
- Flush phase: the producer has completed; the consumer takes all the elements remaining in the reservoir, and finally receives an on-complete signal.

This operator is non-blocking, both in overflow and underflow situations.

**Usage:**

```
ReservoirOperator op = new ReservoirOperator(bufferSize, Schedulers.io());
upstream.lift(op).subscribe(consumer);
```